# How are blinking carets often implemented?

Tags: user-interface, opengl, cross-platform, caret

I'm trying to implement a cross-platform UI library that takes as little system resource as possible. I'm considering to either use my own software renderer or opengl.

For stationary controls everything's fine, I can repaint only when it's needed. However, when it comes to implementing animations, especially animated blinking carets like the 'phase' caret in sublime text, I don't see a easy way to balance resource usage and performance.

For a blinking caret, it's required that the caret be redrawn very frequently(15-20 times per sec at least, I guess). On one hand, the software renderer supports partial redraw but is far too slow to be practical(3-4 fps for large redraw regions, say, 1000x800, which makes it impossible to implement animations). On the other hand, opengl doesn't support partial redraw very well as far as I know, which means the whole screen needs to be rendered at 15-20 fps constantly.

So my question is:

1. How are carets usually implemented in various UI systems?
2. Is there any way to have opengl to render to only a proportion of the screen?

   - I know that glViewport enables rendering to part of the screen, but due to double buffering or other stuff the rest of the screen is not kept as it was. In this way I still need to render the whole screen again.

Comment: If you draw anyhing 15-20 times per second the human eye can not perceive the change. That's why 15-20 fps is the base of desired frame rate. A blinking caret should draw at 0.3-0.6 fps.

Comment: Well, if you look at the caret of sublime text you can notice that it's actually smoothly animated, so I guess that requires higher fps than when it's not animated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to ask yourself.
*Do I really need to partially redraw the screen?*

OpenGL or better said the GPU can draw thousands of triangles at ease. So before you start fiddling with partial redrawing of the screen, then you should instead benchmark and see whether it's worth looking into at all.

This doesn't however imply that you have to redraw the screen endlessly. You can still just redraw it when changes happen.

Thus if you have a cursor blinking every 500 ms, then you redraw once every 500 ms. If you have an animation running, then you continuously redraw while that animation is playing (or every time the animation does a change that requires redrawing).

This is what Chrome, Firefox, etc does. You can see this if you open the Developer Tools (<kbd>F12</kbd>) and go to the Timeline tab.

Take a look at the following screenshot. The first row of the timeline shows how often Chrome redraws the windows.

- The first section shows a lot continuously redrawing. *Which was because I was scrolling around on the page.*
- The last section shows a single redraw every few 500 ms. *Which was the cursor blinking in a textbox.*

*Open the image in a new tab, to see better what's going on.*

[image]

Note that it doesn't tell whether Chrome is fully redrawing the window or only that parts of it. It is just showing the frequency of the redrawing. (*If you want to see the redrawn regions, then both Firefox and Chrome has "Show Paint Rectangles".*)

To circumvent the problem with double buffering and partially redrawing. Then you could instead draw to a framebuffer object. Now you can utilize [`glScissor()`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glScissor.xhtml) as much as you want. If you have various things that are static and only a few dynamic things. Then you could have multiple framebuffer objects and only draw the static contents once and continuously update the framebuffer containing the dynamic content.

However (and I can't emphasize this enough) benchmark and check if this is even needed. Having two framebuffer objects could be more expensive than just always redrawing everything. The same goes for say having a buffer for each rectangle, in contrast to packing all rectangles in a single buffer.

Lastly to give an example let's take [NanoGUI (a minimalistic GUI library for OpenGL)](https://github.com/wjakob/nanogui). NanoGUI continuously redraws the screen.
The *problem* with not *just* continuously redrawing the screen is that now you need a system for issuing a redraw. Now calling `setText()` on a label needs to callback and tell the window to redraw. Now what if the parent panel the label is added to isn't visible? Then `setText()` just issued a redundant redrawing of the screen.

The point I'm trying to make is that if you have a system for issuing redrawing of the screen. Then that might be more prone to errors. Thus unless continuously redrawing is an issue, then that is definitely a more optimal starting point.